# reformat string using sed

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I have a file containing lines

```
["foo"] = ".worldport 0 322.373138 -1487.853882 43.720089",
["bar"] = ".worldport 0 386.938000 212.299000 43.699400",
["baz"] = ".worldport 0 1239.120000 -286.705000 42.476400",
```

which I would like to be edited (keeping the name and values) with sed or awk to become...

```
["foo"]={["position_x"]=322.373138,["position_y"]=-1487.853882,["position_z"]=43.720089,["map"]=0}
["bar"]={["position_x"]=386.938000,["position_y"]=212.299000,["position_z"]=43.699400,["map"]=0}
["baz"]={["position_x"]=1239.120000,["position_y"]=-286.705000,["position_z"]=42.476400,["map"]=0}
```

Comment: But what's your question?

Comment: What have you been trying to do and where have you been stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A perl way:

```
perl -ape 's/ = "\.\w+\h+(\d+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+?)",/={["position_x"]=$2,["position_y"]=$3,[position_z"]=$4,["map"]=$1}/' file.txt
["foo"]={["position_x"]=322.373138,["position_y"]=-1487.853882,[position_z"]=43.720089,["map"]=0}
["bar"]={["position_x"]=386.938000,["position_y"]=212.299000,[position_z"]=43.699400,["map"]=0}
["baz"]={["position_x"]=1239.120000,["position_y"]=-286.705000,[position_z"]=42.476400,["map"]=0}
```

**Explanation:**

```
\w+     # 1 or more word characters
\d+     # 1 or more digits
\h+     # 1 or more horizontal spaces
\S+     # 1 or more NON space characters
```